# How can I either target an Appended element using Jquery or Javascript, or how can I add that appened element to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, socket.io

I've looked all over the internet with everyone giving the same answer

```
     $(document).on('click', '#targetID', function() {
      // do stuff

    });
```

instead of

```
 $('#targetID').click(function() {
      // do stuff

    });
```

This is nice and it works fine, if you have a click event. But within that on click function, the part where it says do stuff, how can I now target an appended element? For instance say I append 2 divs back to back.

```
<div id="mainDiv"></div>

<script>

socket.on('event', function (data)  {
     $('#mainDiv').append ('<div class="1st" id="'+data.id+'">one</div>
    <div class="2nd" id="'+data.id+'">second</div>');
});

     $(document).on('click', '.1st', function() {
      //and right here i would like to`enter something like
      $('.2nd').css('background-color','yellow');
    }

</scirpt>
```

This however seems not to work because to my knowledge, this element hasn't been added to the DOM. So what should I do? Should i use angular.js for this?

PS I've also tried adding the entire appended content into a variable first before appending that variable. and then using variable.find to find the element within to no avail. The variable only has context within that function, but is null in the on click function. Thanks in advance for any information that  broadens my understanding of this.

Answer (score 0):

The delegation of 'on' is correct. Once the div element exists in the dom, clicking  should work. My only concern is you have named your classname beginning with a number. Maybe name it with an alpha character followed by a number.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the 2 is the concept of `event binding vs event delegation.`

`$('#targetID').click(function() {` is `event binding` which works on elements as long as they exist in the markup when the page or document loads.

`$(document).on('click', '#targetID', function() {` is `event delegation` which means the event would listen to the document for the click event on the element with ID `targetID` if it exists in the DOM when the page loads or if it is dynamically added.

So In your case, its `event delegation` since you are dynamically adding the elements. But in order to make it work, you need to register the listener on the `document ready event` for the document to listen to the event on the element #`targetID`

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() // Add this
    {
        socket.on('event', function (data)  {
        $('#mainDiv').append ('<div class="1st" id="'+data.id+'">one</div><div    class="2nd" id="'+data.id+'">second</div>');
        });

         $(document).on('click', '.1st', function() {
          //and right here i would like to`enter something like
          $('.2nd').css('background-color','yellow');
        });
    }); 

</script>
```

Here's an example : https://jsfiddle.net/nobcp0L7/1/